# Referencing web project from ironpython

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

i've got an mvc project written in C#. i'm trying to reference it from ironpython. i've got no issue importing the objects and referencing the dll, but some of the objects rely on connection strings from the web.config, is there any way for me to reference the dll and then specify the web.config it should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Externalize the connection strings into a settings class which can be overriden when using ironpython
- Try one of the two answers to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068396/assembly-redirection-in-code-instead-of-app-config). Neither of them are pretty, but I think for connection strings they might work out.