# Assembly redirection in code instead of app.config

Tags: .net, ironpython, ironruby

I'm using ironruby to execute a script that loads an assembly with a dependency that needs to be redirected from v2.0.0.0 to v3.5.0.0 in the app.config like this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.CompactFramework.Build.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Engine" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

The script works with this redirection, but this requires me to always change the ironruby app.config, and it applies to all scripts.
I need to either:

- define this redirection either for a single script
- execute code that registers the redirection before requiring the problematic assembly

How?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid changing the IronRuby `app.config` by using a hack that I wrote called `configuration_settings_hackery.rb`. You can [read about it](http://vaderpi.com/blog/?p=609) on my blog. The blog post contains a link to a gist on github.

I use this hack every day, and I have been having a lot of success with it. You will need to change the last line of the `configuration_settings_hackery.rb` file to point to the location of your `app.config`. The version that I posted just looks for `c:\app.config`.

Comment: Oh, this looks "nice". I'll try it during the weekend :)

Comment: Okay, on further investigation I'm not sure this will work. 
While this works for configuration values, it doesn't for assembly binding. I think I may need to hook into the events .net fires for assembly resolving.

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a new `AppDomain` with [AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx) set to your special `app.config` and then run your script in that `AppDomain`.